# How do I setup PyQt in my station?

Tags: python, installation, pyqt

I watched streaming videos and searched the internet but seems not clear what are the requirement to set up a PyQt on my workstation. What do you need or what do you do in order to program using PyQt? Please state step by step or a link for step by step setup procedure will do. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your OS is Windows, there are all-in-one binary installers available [here](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download). The only other thing you'll need to install is, of course, python itself.

The latest PyQt4 reference guide is available [here](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/index.html), and the latest Qt Documentation is [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/).

Comment: Thanks. I found this in the link you gave me. http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/installation.html